# How do i charge with payment method like paypal/stripe in Vue js? Do i need a server like express?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, paypal, stripe-payments

I have built a webbshop in Vue js and everything is done but the payment method is missing. Do i need to have express to take charges to stripe? I do not have a server like express now. And if i need express to take charges from paypal sdk or stripe sdk how can i host it later so its not running on my localhost? Its running on localhost port 3000 so how can i make it work on a ftp later?
Anyone that can help me?

I have tried to implement stripe or paypal for a week know but it seems impossible.

Comment: Usually TLS and HTTPS are [required](https://stripe.com/docs/security#tls) to process payments, though I believe with stripe you are able to perform tests over unsecured networks. If you don't want to roll a server you could take a look at [stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout)

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Hmm okey, Im new to server and all that. The only thing i want to do is to charge the customer the product they will buy. And i have some problems to figure out how to do that. What is your best tip to me right now?

Comment: If you want a serverless checkout, perhaps have a look at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout --- otherwise you will need a backend server but it can be something minimal --- aws lambda function, micro heroku instance, even something like firebase (using their http event functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal Checkout will get that done for you:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#

That doc guides you on setting this up directly in your JS app, or you can also use a server back-end with PHP or something else if you prefer.

This will give you PayPal, PayPal Credit, Venmo, and direct credit cards all in a single checkout integration.

Comment: Hey, i have tried this for a long time now but i cant do it:(

Comment: That's not a very helpful comment if you're wanting more help from me.